# Overlapping or Intersecting Circle calculations

Tags: java, geometry, algebra

I have a question pertaining writing a java program and in part of the program it checks if the circles overlap or intersect at any point and displays if they do.

I believe the formula to do this is 
(r1+r2)^2 <= (x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2

After applying this formula to my code it is not able to detect if overlapping or intersecting.

```
    //variables
    //crOneRadius = radius of circle 1
    //crTwoRadius = radius of circle 2
    //crOneCenterX = x axis location of circle 1
    //crOneCenterX = y axis location of circle 1
    //crTwoCenterX = x axis location of circle 2
    //crTwoCenterX = y axis location of circle 2     
    //BOoverlap = is boolean if it is ovelapping circles set to true
    if((crOneRadius+crTwoRadius)*(crOneRadius+crTwoRadius)<=((crTwoCenterX-crOneCenterX)*(crTwoCenterX-crOneCenterX))+((crTwoCenterY-crOneCenterY)*(crTwoCenterY-crOneCenterY)))
        BOoverlap=true;//overlap is true
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? I assume (though it's not in your code in your question) that you initialize BOverlap (BTW, you should not capitalize the first letter of a variable in Java) to false.  Have you observed cases where it's true and should be false, or where it's false and should be true?

Comment: Yes I have observed this It come out false everytime, I'm using java fx to display the two circles and it never is true

Comment: Have you logged/printed the values of the 6 variables and the `BOverlap` result? I suggest you isolate this calculation in its own method and test it with different values (you can write a test in a `main()` method if you don' t want to use JUnit or TestNG).

Comment: BTW, to better see what's going on in the code, I'd also calculate some intermediate values, so the calculation looks more like `sumOfRadii*sumOfRadii <= deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY`. To improve readablity even more, you might even want to write your own `square()` method or use `Math.pow(x,2)`, giving something like `square(sumOfRadii) <= square(deltaX) + square(deltaY)`.

Answer (score 1):

The distance `d` between the two centers `C1` and `C2` must be smaller that the sum of their radii `r1 + r2` for the circles to intercept:

[image]

```
|C1 - C2| <= r1 + r2
```

Squaring both sides

```
(x1 - x2)ˆ2 + (y1 - y2)^2 <= (r1 + r2)^2
```

or

```
(r1 + r2)^2 >= (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2,
```

which is the opposite condition to the one you are using.